# Sheets to Bigquery - set max allowed errors

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, import, error-handling, google-bigquery

I use this script to upload Data from Google Sheets. Its here some way, how to set max errors? I want to just ignore all errors and upload the Data no matter how much errors. I have lot of different big Tables and they are everytime another Format etc.

**I'm able to load this Data correctly manually(i set simply 100 or 1000 Errors allowed). But this script run with autodetect:true and don't allow errors. Thanks**

```
/**
 * Function to run from the UI menu.
 *
 * Uploads the sheets defined in the active sheet into BigQuery.
 */
function runFromUI() {
  // Column indices.
  const SHEET_URL = 1;
  const PROJECT_ID = 2;
  const DATASET_ID = 3;
  const TABLE_ID = 4;
  const APPEND = 5;
  const STATUS = 6;


  // Get the data range rows, skipping the header (first) row.
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);

  // Run the sheetToBigQuery function for every row and write the status.
  rows.forEach((row, i) => {
    let status = sheetToBigQuery(
      row[SHEET_URL],
      row[PROJECT_ID],
      row[DATASET_ID],
      row[TABLE_ID],
      row[APPEND],
    );
    sheet.getRange(i+2, STATUS+1).setValue(status);
  });
}

/**
 * Uploads a single sheet to BigQuery.
 *
 * @param {string} sheetUrl - The Google Sheet Url containing the data to upload.
 * @param {string} projectId - Google Cloud Project ID.
 * @param {string} datasetId - BigQuery Dataset ID.
 * @param {string} tableId - BigQuery Table ID.
 * @param {bool} append - Appends to BigQuery table if true, otherwise replaces the content.
 * 
 * @return {string} status - Returns the status of the job.
 */
function sheetToBigQuery(sheetUrl, projectId, datasetId, tableId, append) {
  try {
    createDatasetIfDoesntExist(projectId, datasetId);
  } catch (e) {
    return `${e}: Please verify your "Project ID" exists and you have permission to edit BigQuery`;
  }

  let sheet;
  try {
    sheet = openSheetByUrl(sheetUrl);
  } catch (e) {
    return `${e}: Please verify the "Sheet URL" is pasted correctly`;
  }

  // Get the values from the sheet's data range as a matrix of values.
  let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Normalize the headers (first row) to valid BigQuery column names.
  // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names
  rows[0] = rows[0].map((header) => {
    header = header.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w]+/g, '_');
    if (header.match(/^\d/))
      header = '_' + header;
    return header;
  });

  // Create the BigQuery load job config. For more information, see:
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery
  let loadJob = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        autodetect: true,  // Infer schema from contents.
        writeDisposition: append ? 'WRITE_APPEND' : 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      }
    }
  };

  // BigQuery load jobs can only load files, so we need to transform our
  // rows (matrix of values) into a blob (file contents as string).
  // For convenience, we convert the rows into a CSV data string.
  // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local
  let csvRows = rows.map(values =>
      // We use JSON.stringify() to add "quotes to strings",
      // but leave numbers and booleans without quotes.
      // If a string itself contains quotes ("), JSON escapes them with
      // a backslash as \" but the CSV format expects them to be
      // escaped as "", so we replace all the \" with "".
      values.map(value => JSON.stringify(value).replace(/\\"/g, '""'))
  );
  let csvData = csvRows.map(values => values.join(',')).join('\n');
  let blob = Utilities.newBlob(csvData, 'application/octet-stream');

  // Run the BigQuery load job.
  try {
    BigQuery.Jobs.insert(loadJob, projectId, blob);
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }

  Logger.log(
    'Load job started. Click here to check your jobs: ' +
    `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=${projectId}&page=jobs`
  );

  // The status of a successful run contains the timestamp.
  // return `Last run: ${new Date().setDate }`;
  return `last run: ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") }`;
}

/**
 * Creates a dataset if it doesn't exist, otherwise does nothing.
 *
 * @param {string} projectId - Google Cloud Project ID.
 * @param {string} datasetId - BigQuery Dataset ID.
 */
function createDatasetIfDoesntExist(projectId, datasetId) {
  try {
    BigQuery.Datasets.get(projectId, datasetId);
  } catch (err) {
    let dataset = {
      datasetReference: {
        projectId: projectId,
        datasetId: datasetId,
      },
    };
    BigQuery.Datasets.insert(dataset, projectId);
    Logger.log(`Created dataset: ${projectId}:${datasetId}`);
  }
}

/**
 * Opens the spreadsheet sheet (tab) with the given URL.
 *
 * @param {string} sheetUrl - Google Sheet Url.
 * 
 * @returns {Sheet} - The sheet corresponding to the URL.
 * 
 * @throws Throws an error if the sheet doesn't exist.
 */
function openSheetByUrl(sheetUrl) {
  // Extract the sheet (tab) ID from the Url.
  let sheetIdMatch = sheetUrl.match(/gid=(\d+)/);
  let sheetId = sheetIdMatch ? sheetIdMatch[1] : null;

  // From the open spreadsheet, get the sheet (tab) that matches the sheetId.
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() == sheetId)[0];
  if (!sheet)
    throw 'Sheet tab ID does not exist';

  return sheet;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the number of max errors, you can use the `maxBadRecords` parameter in your `load` configration. If you want to ignore errors altogether, you can set `ignoreUnknownValues` to `true` instead.

```
  let loadJob = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        autodetect: true,  // Infer schema from contents.
        // maxBadRecords: 1000,
        ignoreUnknownValues: true, // use one or the other
        writeDisposition: append ? 'WRITE_APPEND' : 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      }
    }
  };
```

**References:**

[BigQuery v2 | Job Configuration Load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad)

Comment: ignoreUnknownVlaues did not help, nut maxBadErrors did! Thx

Comment: Very much appreciated!